# correct syntax for form tag in rails three with haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have been trying to get form_tag to work in haml. However i can't get it to work without errors such as unexpected and undefined errors. I was therefore wondering if there was something significantly different i should be doing for rails 3.

```
= form_tag url: complete_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), html: {method: :put} do |f|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`form_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), you don't need `url:` or `html:`. Just using

```
= form_tag complete_diagnostic_path(@diagnostic), method: :put do
```

should work for you.